# {$\mathbb u$ $\in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ , such that $u=0$ , $ \Delta u=0 $ on $\partial \Omega $} $\subseteq$ $W^{2,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have a question that it maybe simple but I can not understand why we have :

> {$\mathbb u$ $\in W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ , such that $u=0$ , $ \Delta u=0 $ on $\partial \Omega $} $\subseteq$ $W^{2,2}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$

Should I use some inequality? Or is it obvious from definition?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $\Delta u = 0$ only on the boundary?

Comment: @John Ma  : Yes on the boundary

Comment: Then how do you define $\Delta u =0$ and $u = 0$ on the boundary? In general the boundary has measure zero.

Comment: @JohnMa : there is no problem to define u=0 on the boundary (looks for trace operator), but $\Delta u$ seems to be only $L^2$, so it's strange (the usual trace operator doesn't works )

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator

Comment: In any case the condition $u=0$ on the boundary automatically (assuming some regularity of the domain) implies that $u\in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Jose27 : sry, can you explain some more, thanks.

Comment: Please give a reference to this claim. Otherwise it's not clear what the statement even means, let alone why it should be true.

Comment: @ 1999 : see the last of the page 3  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uam.es%2Fpersonal_pdi%2Fciencias%2Fmapperez%2Fultimos_trabajos%2FPerezPrimoRevised.pdf&ei=JSSeVf3aGar6ywPvvqvYCg&usg=AFQjCNEWUiwjrczoQQhswakkxluVyOuXHQ&sig2=SU-ueZ24BFA_-qO5JY2Zhg&bvm=bv.96952980,d.bGg